# Pass parameter to Bash function which will serve as a pattern to awk

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to know how to pass a argument to a Bash function which would consequently serve as a pattern to awk. I have read several Q/As which tend to answer the same question, however, I am missing something.

I use the following one-liner to find a package, which in this example is vivaldi, using Arch Linux `packman`:

```
 pacman -Sl | awk '$2~ /^vivaldi/{print $2, $3, $4, "[" $1 "]"}' | sort
```

I've written the following function but executing it outputs no result:

```
function pacname() {
    #pattern="$1"
    pacman -Sl | awk -v pattern="$1" '$2~ /^"pattern"/{print $2, $3, $4, "[" $1 "]"}' | sort
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not expanded inside Awk's `/.../` regex. Instead you can use the string form `"^"pattern` to concatenate the anchor operator with a variable pattern value.

Ex.

```
echo 'baz foobar' | awk -v pattern="foo" '$2 ~ "^"pattern {print $1}'
baz
```

Comment: Or even construct the regex in the `-v` text: `awk -v pattern="^$1" '$2 ~ pattern {...`